# preloading issue on ipad

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, ipad

i want to Preload 152 jpg images for 7 animations.I am trying to run individual animation as soon as images required for that animation(ex first 40 images) has preloaded.In all browser it's working fine as well as in android also.But in ipad, animation(background-image changing) is not running smoothly untill all 152 images won't preload.

```
function preload(arguments,index) {
    console.log(index)
    for(var i=1;i<=eval(imagesPerScreen[index][1]-imagesPerScreen[index][0]+1);i++){

        scheen[index][i-1] = new Image();
        scheen[index][i-1].src = arguments[index][eval(i-1)];


        $(scheen[index][i-1]).load(function(){
            imgLoaded++;
            var percent=parseInt((imgLoaded/(imagesPerScreen[index][1]-imagesPerScreen[index][0]+1)*100).toFixed())+8;

            if(!isiPad){
                //document.getElementById("loadingStatus").innerHTML="loading.. "+percent+"%";
                $("#loadingStatus").css('width',percent+'px');


            }
            else{
                //$("#loadingStatus").css('display','none');
                $("#loadingStatus").css('width',percent+'px');  


            }

        }); 

    }


    scheen[index][eval(imagesPerScreen[index][1]-imagesPerScreen[index][0])].onload= function() {

            ++screenLoaded;

            imgLoaded=0;

                $("#rightbutton").css('display','block');   
                $("#rightArea").css('display','block');
                $("#loadingStatus").css('display','none');  
                $("#status").fadeOut("fast");
                $("#preloader").fadeOut("fast");    


            if(waiting){moveNext();}

            if(screenLoaded<7){ 
                preload(pics,index+1)           
            }


    };  }
```